# How do I setup application shortcuts to work without opening the menu manually?

Tags: ms-office, shortcut

I have setup application shortcuts for my signatures in Outlook 2011 for Mac as described [here](http://robandlauren.com/2011/10/13/creating-keyboard-shorcuts-in-outlook-for-mac/).  However, the shortcuts don't work unless I first click the signatures dropdown.  It seems like the shortcuts aren't loaded until I click the dropdown.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Neat trick, never thought about it!

So I tried this and I could repro your scenario, the signature will not be inserted until the "signature" dropdown is invoked.  I found that this had to be done **every** time you wanted to invoke the shortcut, which is a clear bummer.

I also found that when composing a message right after Outlook starts,  if you select (from the main menu):

Draft -> Signatures (select nothing just let the menu go once the signature submenu is displayed)

Then the shortcut will work for all the messages you compose thereafter.

Not the best solution, but better than having to click that signature dropdown everytime.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to stand on its own.

Comment: Definitely an interesting workaround.